# Combine Data From Separate Columns with a Delimiter with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QXDc5NWKU5oWpbzXR_FUojb9FUrH-uJjeDomMevP_JU/edit#gid=0) is the example sheet.

Alright, in cell `V1!A1` is the formula `={"Languages";ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F&","),,COLUMNS(B2:F))))}`. I need to combine data from `B2:F` with the delimiter  `,`. But now I need to delete the unnecessary delimiters. 
In sheet `V2`, I tried `={"Languages";ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F&","),,COLUMNS(B2:F))),"(^(,(\s,){4})$)|(^(,\s)+)|(,(\s,)?\s?$)",""),"(,\s,)+\s?",", "))}` but it's not consistant and still leaves delimiters in the output.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a sheet called "Erik Help" which replaces your formula with the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Languages";SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:F&" "),,COLUMNS(B2:F))))," ",", ")})
```

Essentially, instead of appending a comma to elements of the range B2:F, I appended a space. Then I applied TRIM to the results, which will leave no spaces before or after each concatenation and only one between each element. To that, I applied a SUBSTITUTE of the single spaces with a comma-space.